# setAnimation not always working why?

Tags: android, animation

Building this app, I have managed to use some animations
using them with View view.setAnimation() etc..

This is the code i have:

```
 // animation Properties
    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); // add this
    fadeIn.setDuration(5000);

    AnimationSet animation1 = new AnimationSet(false); // change to false
    //animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animation1.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animation1.setRepeatCount(1);

    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); // and this
    //fadeOut.setStartOffset(fadeInDuration + timeBetween);
    fadeOut.setDuration(5000);

    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); // change to false
    //animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);


    textViewTopBannerBizName.setAnimation(animation1);

    textViewTopBannerBizCategory.setAnimation(animation1);
```

So all, I want is that `textViewTopBannerBizName` and `textViewTopBannerBizCategory` will fade into screen as i used **animation1** for both of them.

However first time when i launched the app it worked perfect but when I relaunched it again it stopped working.

It makes me wonder... why...?

Please help, 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

try this.(Tested)

```
textViewTopBannerBizName.startAnimation(animation1);
```

You can clear animation if cached before by calling `clearAnimation()` and then startAnimation or setAnimation.

**Edited**

setAnimation

Sets the next animation to play for this view.But view animation does not start yet.

startAnimation

If you want the animation to play immediately, use startAnimation. This method provides allows fine-grained control over the start time and invalidation, but you must make sure that

1) the animation has a start time set,

2) the view will be invalidated when the animation is supposed to start

Comment: Can you explain the difference between startAnimation and setAnimation ?

Answer (score 0):

After setting animation, Please do invalidate the view if it's not an Activity

```
 imb6.setAnimation(MainActivity.blinkAnimation(mContext, true))
 invalidate();
```

I wish this'll helps.